# If $AP^2=P^2A$ then $AP=PA$

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

I am trying to show that

*"Let $A$ be a normal operator and $P$ be a positive operator such that
$AP^2=P^2A$.

Then $AP=PA$."

A hint is given as the following.

We should prove that

If $x \in \ker(P)$ then $(AP−PA)x=0$.

If $x \in range(P)$ then $(AP−PA)x=0$.

Therefore, $AP−PA=0$.

I tried to give in detail but it still gets in struck.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Positive and not positive *definite*?

Comment: Yes, it is positive. Even it is positive definite, I think the result does not change.

Comment: Well, positive definite would at least allow you to cancel some things, so that's why I ask. Of course if you *strengthen* the hypotheses a result does not change. I think it' makes a difference.   Anyhow, it looks like it definitely depends upon the "normal" and "positive" hypotheses, if true. The algebra alone doesn't seem to yield an answer.

Comment: See theorem 10 on p.23 of Bernau (1967), [*The square root of a positive self-adjoint operator*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S1446788700004560), J. Australian Math. Soc., 8(1): 17-36, in which $T$ is your $P^2$, $B$ is your $P$ and $A$, being normal, is closed.

Comment: Should we prove this result without the hypothesis that P is self-afjoint?  I read on the paper, they mentioned about positive self-adjoint operator. In our question, "self-adjoint" property is obmitted.